# Login API with node-fetch

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

I can easily login to this website, however I can't get this API to authorize with `node-fetch`. It always returns `403 Forbidden`

I've tried:

1. PostMan, cURL and they didn't work.
2. Varios CORS headers.
3. I've copy the CSRF from the page and use it in the login request. (I can see this is the approach the site uses)

The URL is the login URL of [www.shaderfrog.com](http://www.shaderfrog.com)

Here's what the Chrome debugger says is the request in `Fetch with NodeJS` format.

**Any insights into what might be missing?**

```
fetch("https://www.shaderfrog.com/api/login", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"98\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"98\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "x-csrf-token": "ppbn3Bip-4Yuem2s3zhpGCoKUcAqeIzXA1Es",
    "cookie": "connect.sid=s%3AibP0n0mKGusxFnAZWaZE2xCV76U_zLvy.sJVm6lfcbr7AfCVqY%2B1ndy23qK%2F0suGESSx5t5%2FFI%2Fw; _ga=GA1.2.799973656.1646711862; _gid=GA1.2.676829117.1646711862; _gat=1",
    "Referer": "https://www.shaderfrog.com/app",
    "Referrer-Policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
  },
  "body": "{\"username\":\"<username>\",\"password\":\"<password\"}",
  "method": "POST"
});
```

Comment: CSRF tokens cannot be re-used. If you're trying to sign in programatically, you'll also need to retrieve a new CSRF token in whatever manner the normal flow uses

Comment: @Phil Yes I've tried cURL and Postman. Also will add: I captured the CSRF from the page and used it only one time in the request; still forbidden (just search the landing page for "csrf" and its there to capture), <edited page>